# Problem not showing Activity_Main.xml on virtual machine

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I created two buttons and a TextView in **activity_main.xml** in **android studio**. And when I run inside the **virtual machine**. It does not work well ...
**Virtual machine** is different from **Activity_main.xml**, how can I fix this problem?

this is my **Activity_main.xml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonone"
        android:layout_width="70.2dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="651dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="331dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="T"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded,SpUsage" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="347dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="195dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="159dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my **AndroidManifest.xml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.appfirst">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppFirst"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And this is the virtual machine image and Activity_main.xml

[image]

Comment: `android:layout_marginTop="651dp"` that's a massive amount to be moving a view down, you're probably moving it out of the screen, you also have a massive amount of stuff you're ignoring - `tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded,SpUsage"` which is usually a sign of a beginner or someone who doesn't understand layouts, probably a good idea to review some basics

Comment: I did what you said thats work on one button but not work on another...

Comment: well, when i said review the basics, it wasn't to be rude, i just think it would help a lot, from your layout i seems clear that you're just starting out with this, so review some basics and see if you can resolve it afterwards

Comment: try removing `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp"` to see where your button _actually_ is